# BizTalk 2016 SAP NCo

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I'm currently migrating from BizTalk 2010 to BizTalk 2016. At the same time I'm also migrating from ClassRfc to NCo for the SAP adapter.

With the first RFC call that I make, I noticed that the decimal separator is a comma instead of a period.
I checked with some idocs I receive and there it is still the period as I would expect.

Has somebody experienced the same issue before?

Comment: Have you checked the language settings in SAP for NCo RFC calls?

Comment: Just changed the regional settings for the Host instance account and it's working now. Seems that NCo is taking that settings into account while classic RFC din't

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the regional settings of your host instance account are used. Mine was set to the default "Dutch (Belgium)". Changing the decimal sign fixed the issue.